# Babel with core-js - Polyfills not IE11 compatible

Tags: webpack, babeljs, core-js

I have configured babel with webpack and initially used @babel/polyfill as an entry in the webpack config. With this configuration I was able to run my web app in IE11 without any errors. Since @babel/polyfill is deprecated I tried to use core-js which is where my problems started. IE11 now gives me an error for the file webpack:///node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.set-prototype-of.js:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

The script itself looks like this:

[image]

As far as I understand, core-js shouldn't be included in the babel-loader to be transpiled but it looks to me like the above shown script uses features which IE11 does not understand. What am I missing here?

The current configuration looks like this:

**babel-loader**

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    configFile: './.babelrc',
  },
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": {"version": 3, "proposals": true}
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
 "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
 ]
```

I also removed @babel/polyfill from the webpack entries and the package manager and instead installed core-js.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "exclude" option to see if is a npm module.
Then you can try to exclude all modules except that one. 
You can see the modules that @babel/preset-env is affected with the option 'debug', like this (in your file .babelrc):

```
 {
  "sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": {"version": 3, "proposals": true},
        "debug": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

To exclude only the module that is giving the error you can do it like this:

```
    exclude: /node_modules\\(?!(module_to_include|other_module_to_include)).*/,
```

See if 
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171 helps

Comment: Try to argument your answer better, maybe with some citations and/or code snippets from the  github project you linked. It is fine to use links as answers but the information should also be available in case the link won't work in the future.